# Post request form data not received on express backend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I tried making a form that was supposed to submit a file to an express backend but for some reason in the backend, I am not receiving the data when I submit the form.

On using `console.log` I get `{}` for  **req.body** and `undefined` for **sampleFile**

Here is the html form,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta
   http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
   content="IE=edge" />
  <meta
   name="viewport"
   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link
   rel="stylesheet"
   href="./styles/styles.css" />

  <title>Upload </title>
 </head>

 <form
  ref="uploadForm"
  name='uploadForm'
  id="uploadForm"
  action="http://localhost:4000/partners"
  method="post"
  encType="multipart/form-data">
   <input
     id="upload" type='file'  name="input1"
     placeholder="Upload file"  />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this is the express backend route handling the post request,

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.post('/partners', async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body, '>>>>>>>body')
  console.log(req.files, '>>>>>>>files')
  
})
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server running on port 4000'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process file uploads you need a multipart encoder for Express. You can use the [Multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) middleware library for that.

```
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

const app = express()

app.post('/partners', upload.single('partner'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `partner` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: I had used a package called called xlsx to extract data from xlsx and csv files and it was working perfectly fine 3 days ago. But now for some reason its not.  I used the solution given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74161255/how-to-extract-data-from-xlsx-or-csv-file-as-json